# Hypothesis testing library unable to find a failing example for this simple arithmetic problem

Tags: python, testing, hypothesis-test

I am trying to learn the *hypothesis* testing library for python and I came up with the following example (taken from a math channel in youtube) which is a very simple arithmetic problem: find `x, y, w, z` such that

`x*y = 21 & x+w = 8 & y*z = 9 & w - z = 5`

The solution is `x = 2.1, y = 10, w = 5.9, z = 0.9`. Using *hypothesis* as a declarative programming library, I was expecting to find the solution rather quickly.

The code I used with *hypothesis* is:

```py
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st
from typing import Tuple

def f(a: float, b: float, c: float ,d: float) -> Tuple[float]:
    return (a*b, a+c, b*d, c-d)

@given(
    st.tuples(
        st.floats(min_value=0),
        st.floats(min_value=0),
        st.floats(min_value=0),
        st.floats(min_value=0)
    )
)
def test_f(f32_tuple):
    assert f(*f32_tuple) != (21, 8, 9, 5)
```

After launching it a few times with pytest, *hypothesis* is unable to find the solution.
At first I thought it was a floating point comparison problem, or maybe the search space is just too enormous, so I decided to cut it back to integers (modifying the last number in the tuple), for example:

```py
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st
from typing import Tuple

def f(a: float, b: float, c: float ,d: float) -> Tuple[float]:
    return (a*b, a+c, b*d, c-d)

@given(
    st.tuples(
        st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=10),
        st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=10),
        st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=10),
        st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=10),
    )
)
def test_f(f32_tuple):
    assert f(*f32_tuple) != (21, 8, 9, -2)
```

Here, the solution would be the tuple `(7, 3, 1, 3)`, the search space has "only" 10^4 elements so I expected it to find a solution after a few runs.

This behavior concerns me, since the usefulness of the library lies in its ability to detect cases one would not come up with normally.

Am I using the generators wrong? Or is *hypothesis* unable to deal with such cases? I need to know if I am going to use it in a day-to-day basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothesis uses a variety of heuristics to find "interesting" inputs, but is essentially still throwing random data at your function.
[By default](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#hypothesis.settings.max_examples), hypothesis only makes 100 attempts. You can increase this, however, with a decorator like `@settings(max_examples=20000)`. Adding this to your bounded-integer version is sufficient to get Hypothesis to find the solution:

```
-------------------------------------------- Hypothesis --------------------------------------------
Falsifying example: test_f(
    f32_tuple=(7, 3, 1, 3),
)
===================================== short test summary info ======================================
FAILED so_arith.py::test_f - assert (21, 8, 9, -2) != (21, 8, 9, -2)
```

In many practical situations, this randomized approach works quite well! But not in the example you have here.

This kind of problem is best analyzed with a constraint solver. [CrossHair](https://github.com/pschanely/CrossHair) is a solver-based system for checking Python properties, and can handle the unbounded version. (disclaimer: I am the primary maintainer!) Here is the CrossHair equivalent of your example:

```
from typing import Tuple

def f(a: float, b: float, c: float ,d: float) -> Tuple[float]:
    """ post: _ != (21, 8, 9, -2) """
    return (a*b, a+c, b*d, c-d)
```

[Running](https://crosshair-web.org/?crosshair=0.1&python=3.8&gist=20e47cbf2bc402a698e9ed18bf3a67f2) `crosshair check` on this file produces the output you expect:

```
/tmp/main.py:4: error: false when calling f(a = 7.0, b = 3.0, c = 1.0, d = 3.0) (which returns (21.0, 8.0, 9.0, -2.0))
```